# How to open filedialog to retrieve file path in Flet (Python)?

Tags: python, flet

How can I open a filedialog in flet-python to retrieve a file path? I tried with other libraries (tkinter creates a new event loop, easygui throws the windows to the back of all other windows, wx needs to create a loop too).

I needed just that, to open a filedialog, choose the file and the function returning the path chosen. I'm using flet-python, so if a solution is available within the library, it would be perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot docs for FLET [Filepicker](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/filepicker). 
I think this code can help you:

```
import flet
from flet import (Page, FilePicker, Text,
                  ElevatedButton, Row, Column, FilePickerResultEvent)


def main(page: Page):   
# 2) CREATE THE EVENT FOR FILEPICKER (TO OPEN THE FILEPICKER DIR WINDOW)
    def select_file(e: FilePickerResultEvent):
        page.add(filepicker)
        filepicker.pick_files("Select file...")
# 3) CREATE THE FUNCTION OF EVENT
    def return_file(e: FilePickerResultEvent): 
        file_path.value = e.files[0].path
        file_path.update()

    row_filepicker = Row(vertical_alignment="center")
    file_path = Text(value="Selected file path", expand=1)
# 1) CREATE A FILEPICKER:
    filepicker = FilePicker(on_result=return_file)
    
    
    row_filepicker.controls.append(
        ElevatedButton(
            text="Select file...", on_click=select_file))
    # ADD THE PATH (if you will select it)
    row_filepicker.controls.append(
        file_path)
        
    page.add(row_filepicker)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Yeh.. Right now, it is possible. They added the filepicker.

Answer (score 1):

I use a function dialogpicker, like this:

```
def dialogpicker(e:FilePickerResultEvent):
    # e.files is a list of files 
    if e.files is None: return
      for x in e.files:
      #do_something
      # x.name to get the name of the file
      # x.path to get the path of the file
    pass
```

You have to assign that function to the picker:

```
pick = FilePicker(on_result=dialogpicker)
page.overlay.append(pick)
```

Then, if you want to trigger it, you have to call the picker:

```
# function assigned to a button to get the file (allow_multiple = False if you want only one file)
def pick_file(e):
    pick.pick_files(allow_multiple=True)
```